# How to List all the Excel COM Addins Using C# ?

Tags: c#

I would like to list all the Excel COM Addins installed on my machine and write to Console using C#. Could anyone provide me a code snippet for this question.

For example, I have installed 5 Excel COM AddIns in my machine and I would like to list out all of them and write them to Console.

Currently I am using the following to count the number of COM Addins.

**Microsoft.Office.Core.COMAddIns.Count**

Answer (score 0):

The `COMAddIns` property implements `IEnumerable`, so you can simply loop over it:

```
foreach (COMAddIn addIn in application.COMAddIns) {
    Console.WriteLine(addIn.ProgId);
}
```